# Umbraco Azure site gives 502

Tags: database, azure, umbraco, webmatrix

Very often when I publish my Umbraco site to Azure it will cause a 502 page to be returned when looking at the remote site. After reading some forum posts and following suggestions I believe it is the database that is the problem. When I delete it and reinstall from local it's fine, if I try to overwrite a running site it very often causes problems, if I stop the webserver it sometimes causes problems. It's pretty inconsistent.

Also the only reliable way to transfer files is Webmatrix as FTP won't show the files and Git doesn't do anything.

Does anybody know a full proof way of updating the database (.sdf file) without too much hassle?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you want to deploy a third party application to Windows Azure rather than write your own. You can post such questions on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/. This forum is used to discuss development problems, while that forum is used to discuss management and deployment issues.

Answer (score 0):

The umbraco process sometimes hangs onto the sdf file.  One thing you can do though is to take the site offline and restart the app pool as part of your publish.  Unfortunately, this will mean downtime for the site during publish, and you’ll also need to perform a few passes.

Steps to get around this:

1. Add a file named app_offline.htm to the root of your site.  This will prevent people from pinging the site and causing Umbraco to grab the db while you are updating it.
2. Make a change to your web.config (not sure if this is necessary, but this forces your app pool to restart… which forces it to let go of your sdf file)
3. Publish everything
4. Remove the app_offline.htm from your site